# Is this oregano?

Tags: identification

Found it in the wilderness (Southeastern Europe)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your nose tell you?

Comment: Mentha pulegium ?

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing, no? The leaves look right but the flowers are wrong. Oregano has dense terminal spikes of flowers, these have whorls of flowers that are the right colour but down on the stem, not up at the top. If it has a square stem then this confirms is in the mint family as the whorls would indicate, but this family is very broad; typical mint leaves are a different shape. [This article](https://sammisherbs.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/mint/) has a picture of similar leaves that might help you in combination with the odour when crushing a leaf.